# Is there a limit to the number of times GTA V can be installed on other computers?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How many times can I install GTA 5 on different computers?
I wanted to know if I can share with my friends and family.

Answer (score 2):

> How many times can I install GTA 5 on different desktops?

You can install GTA V on many PC's as you want, but you can only play from one at the same time.

> I can share with my friends and family?

No, you can't share either Social Club or Steam editions.

As you may heard, [Steam family sharing](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing) will allow you to share games with other users. Because GTA V uses a 3rd party DRM (RGSC) you cannot share this specific game with other Steam users (this also happens with other Rockstar titles like GTA IV and Max Payne 3).